# bypass proxy to add service reference

Tags: .net, proxy, service-reference

I need to add a service reference to my `.Net` project but proxy locks my actions (Error: proxy authentication required).
How can I do that?

Comment: Please, have a look at the answers to the similar question [add web service reference from behind a proxy server][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7386586/456456