# Issue on a web service request

Tags: c#, asmx

I'm quite new to web service development, so please bear with me.

I'm trying to make an asmx web service call. On the test development machines here in our office, there is absolutely no problem. However, on a clients site, there is an issue with 2 of their machines, but no issue on another machine.

I'm getting the following error on the aforementioned 2 machines when trying to make the outgoing web service request:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Policy Jump</title>
    <meta name="id" content="policyJump" >
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
</head>
<BODY>This document has moved <A href="http://128.2.2.254/dynPolLoginRedirect.html">here</A> </BODY>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you look at that page?

Answer (score 0):

That page is a proxy login page. You need to authenticate the call from the client site.

If your next question then is *"How?"*, you should ask their network administrators. For authenticating the call, see for example [add web service reference from behind a proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386452/add-web-service-reference-from-behind-a-proxy-server).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. It was a permissions issue on the client side. The client network admins have allocated the appropriate permissions for the URL in question.